# Gist revisions limit?

Tags: github, gist

I created a gist to store some casual changes to files. The gist is now at revision 14, and cannot save new changes.

The AJAX call shows an `aborted` message after trying to post to `https://gist.github.com/AstDerek/<gist-id>`

And a redirection to `https://collector.githubapp.com/gist/page_view?dimensions[page]=https%3A%2F%2Fgist.github.com%2FAstDerek%2F<gist-id>&dimensions[title]=Gists&dimensions[referrer]=&dimensions[user_agent]=<browser-details>&dimensions[screen_resolution]=<res>&dimensions[pixel_ratio]=1&dimensions[browser_resolution]=<res>&dimensions[timestamp]=<ts>&&dimensions[actor_id]=<id>&dimensions[actor_login]=AstDerek&dimensions[actor_hash]=<some-hash>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems there is no limit on editions.

For example, [one of my gists](https://gist.github.com/weakish/911335/) has 73 revisions.

Comment: So far mine has 90 revisions and growing.

Comment: i have a gist with 1,379 revisions - and growing

Comment: @hanshenrik For curiosity, how many seconds or minutes to load the "revisions" tab of the gist?

Comment: @weakish it only shows 30 revisions per page before giving a "next button", and the revisions are only 1 line each, so just a second. `real 0m1.843s user 0m0.093s sys 0m0.062s` -- `time curl --compressed 'https://gist.github.com/x-ratma-net-bot/bbea2ecec2598a790487bea921b87e0d/revisions'`  (sorry, some weird invisible unicode characters snuck into the url on first attempt to write this comment, no idea how, thus rewriting it) edit 2: it seems to be a bug with stackoverflow comment system. try manually resolving https://goo.gl /WCjcHJ (and furthermore, url shorteners are banned, wtf SO?)

Answer (score 0):

this gist has over 10,000 revisions: https://gist.github.com/x-ratma-net-bot/bbea2ecec2598a790487bea921b87e0d

and funnily enough, once you hit 10,000 revisions, gist will no longer tell you how many revisions it has, only that it is "10,000+ revisions"